# Naming convention for Drupal views

Tags: views, theming

I have a view setup named `Homepage Suppliers`.

It is a jCarousel format that displays an image field which links to the content.

What I'm looking to do, is theme this using a view template to get it exactly how I want it.

I've tried using the following file names:

`views-view--homepage-suppliers.tpl.php`

`views-view-list--homepage-suppliers.tpl.php`

Do these look right?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Views has a nice built-in way to help you decipher which template filename(s) to use.

Open up your view in edit mode, go to the display that you're interested in, and open up the 'Advanced' tab. Right at the bottom you'll see the "Theme: Information" link. Click that, and you'll be presented with a popup that looks something like this:

[image]

Once you've decided on the right filename, create the file and populate it, then make sure to clear Drupal's theme registry caches or the changes won't get picked up.

Comment: where exactly do you create the file (sites/all/themes/mytheme/templates?)? And is this true for views 3 on drupal 7?